# Which subject does the author try to indicate in this extract?

Tags: meaning

The extract:

> "That freedom can never be attained by a nation without suffering and sacrifice, has been amply borne out by the recent tragic happenings in this sub-continent," said Jinnah.

The above second sentence does not contain the subject or agent, as it says:

> "...has been amply borne out by the recent tragic happenings in this sub-continent." said Jinnah.

But, I could not understand that which subject (e.g. He, she, it) is being used.

Comment: Are you sure the first word of the extract is _the_? The sentence works if the first word is _that_ (and the comma omitted).

Comment: It should be "that": https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/muhammad_ali_jinnah_372014

Comment: @OliverMason do you mean: sacrifice has been amply borne out...?

Comment: @IqbalAhmedSiyal No, the fact that freedom cannot be attained without it.

Comment: @Oliver Now, I replaced 'the' with 'that'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subject is the clause "That freedom can never be attained by a nation without suffering and sacrifice". It takes third-person singular agreement (like the pronoun "it"), as shown by the use of "has" as the inflected finite verb of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to see if you rephrase the sentence as:

*It has been amply borne out by the recent tragic happenings in this subcontinent that freedom can never be attained by a nation without suffering and sacrifice.*

Or: *Recent tragic events [...] show that freedom can never be attained [...]*

So the meaning is that it is impossible for a nation to attain freedom without suffering and sacrifice, as shown by recent events [in India/Pakistan].